# How to reset and re-render components using react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to React Hooks.

I have been working on re-rendering after the button is clicked.

[My Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-forked-3x5c8?file=/src/index.js)

From my example, there are two buttons. One is to increment the count and the other is to remove the content. When I click a `remove` button, the content becomes null in order to reset the count.

What I want to try is to display the new content with the new count which is zero when the `render` button is clicked.

However, the issue is when I click the `render` button, it shows nothing.

I believe that the reason is because I have set `null` to remove the content in my condition which is logically incorrect. I have looked at the other questions related to this problem, but I haven't found any proper way to solve it.

Can anybody help me to figure this out?

Comment: Based on the example linked above, you're never actually your `render` never changes in functionality, so you won't be able to render the data once it's been removed. You just need to update the `render` button's `onClick` to `onClick={() => setRender(!render)}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I want to try is to display the new content with the new count
> which is zero when the render button is clicked.

You can use a React key on an abstracted component that when updated, informs React that it's a "new" component and the old one should be unmounted and the new one mounted, essentially resetting it.

Example:

```
const Counter = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox {count}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Increment</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Use the toggling `render` state to toggle a new React key so `Counter` is remounted with initial state.

```
function App() {
  const [render, setRender] = useState(true);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Counter key={render} />
      <button onClick={() => setRender(!render)}>
        remove
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

## Demo

[image: Edit how-to-reset-and-re-render-components-using-react-hooks]

Answer (score 1):

The state provenient from the useState hooks belong to the App component. What you're doing is conditionally rendering a part of this component based on your current App state. From what I get it you have to setCount(0) manually to have your state clean. It's not possible to deconstruct a component from the inside out.
Using a useEffect you can check when the component is constructed and destructed.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log('constructed');
  return () => {
    console.log('destructed');
  }
}, []);
```